# Only saving disinct rows in temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, distinct

I have a query where I want the sum of the costs found in #temp_costs, and I want to group them per version_id (To see what the total costs of a company are)
The total cost are calculated together with a certain type of costs where the column is_included is either 0 or 1.  #temp_costs_count is a previously created table.

However because the following query takes place in a loop (I cannot take it out of the loop) Say it loops over 4 companies, I end up with a list looking something like:

[image: What it looks like right now]

And this is what it desirably should look like

[image: What it should look like]

This is my code right now

```
  insert into  #temp_costs_count (
    version_id,
    total_costs,
    cost_included
    )

        select  version_id,
                count(*),
                sum(case when is_included = 1 then 1 else 0 end)
        from #temp_costs
        group by version_id

        select * 
        from #temp_costs_count
```

I do get the wished result by running

```
select distinct * 
from #temp_costs_count
```

However Is there a way I can use an update statement so it's saved like this in #temp_costs_count as wel?

Comment: Sorry, but you want the distinct data put back in `#temp_costs_count` or put into `#temp_kosten_count`?  Perhaps those are the same and you've translated, but clearing things up a little would be swell.  In the first case, a solution I've used that may not be ideal, but perhaps it would be better to initially insert into a second `#temp` table and then you can simply `INSERT INTO #temp_costs_count (version_id, total_costs, cost_included) SELECT DISTINCT * 
from #temp_table2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I skipped over why you needed this and just looked at the other answers - but as the intention seems to be to skip inserting rows that already exist you can achieve this by adding the following to the `#temp` table.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix
  ON #temp_costs_count(version_id, total_costs, cost_included)
  WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON);
```

then any duplicates will be identified efficiently and ignored without any need to change the query

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`EXCEPT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to only insert records that don't already exist in your table. e.g:

```
INSERT #temp_costs_count (version_id, total_costs, cost_included)
SELECT  version_id,
        count(*),
        sum(case when is_included = 1 then 1 else 0 end)
FROM    #temp_costs
GROUP BY version_id
EXCEPT
SELECT version_id, total_costs, cost_included
FROM    #temp_costs_count;
```

Or if you are defining a duplicate differently (e.g. just a record with that particular `version_id`),then you can use [`NOT EXISTS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) e.g.:

```
INSERT #temp_costs_count (version_id, total_costs, cost_included)
SELECT version_id,
        count(*),
        sum(case when is_included = 1 then 1 else 0 end)
FROM    #temp_costs AS tc
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM temp_costs_count AS tcc WHERE tcc.version_id = tc.version_id)
GROUP BY version_id;
```

---

*As an aside, I can probably count on one hand the number of times I have **had** to use a loop in SQL Server (and I have spent pretty much every working day for the last 12 years writing SQL). In my experience, in about 99.9% of cases where someone thinks they need to use a loop, they don't, and there is a much more efficient set based solution out there.*

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the non existence of a record in a `HAVING` clause using `NOT EXISTS` and a correlated subquery. That is, no record is selected and therefore inserted, when it already exists.

```
INSERT INTO #temp_costs_count
            (version_id,
             total_costs,
             cost_included)
            SELECT tc.version_id,
                   count(*),
                   sum(CASE
                         WHEN tc.is_included = 1 THEN
                           1
                         ELSE
                           0
                       END)
                   FROM #temp_costs tc
                   GROUP BY tc.version_id
                   HAVING NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                             FROM #temp_costs_count tcc
                                             WHERE tcc.version_id = version_id
                                                   AND tcc.total_costs = count(*)
                                                   AND tcc.cost_included = sum(CASE
                                                                                 WHEN tc.is_included = 1 THEN
                                                                                   1
                                                                                 ELSE
                                                                                   0
                                                                               END));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery with a distinct:

```
insert into  #temp_costs_count (
version_id,
total_costs,
cost_included
)
select distinct version_id,total_costs,cost_included from (
    select  version_id,
            count(*) as total_costs,
            sum(case when is_included = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as cost_included
    from #temp_costs
    group by version_id

). as q
```